# JSON Schema for array of different types with mandatory property fails validation

Tags: arrays, object, jsonschema, required

I created the following draft4 schema:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "$id": "catalog.structs.schema.json",
    "definitions": {
         "geography": {
            "type": "object",
            "description": "Geographical location which may or may not be part of a hierarchy.",
            "properties": {
                "geography_type": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": ["union", "country", "state"] 
                },
                "name": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": ["Turkey", "Netherlands"]
                },
                "parent": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/geography"
                }
            },
            "required": ["name"]
        },
        "geography_group": {
            "type": "array",
            "description": "A grouping of discrete geographies that are not necessarily in a common hierarchy.",
            "items": {
                "type" : "object",
                "$ref": "#/definitions/geography"
            }
        }
    },
    "oneOf": [{
        "properties": {
            "geography": { "type": "object", "$ref": "#/definitions/geography"},
            "geography_group" : { "type": "object", "$ref": "#/definitions/geography_group"}
        },
        "additionalProperties": false
    }]
}
```

The following validates correctly against the schema

```
{"geography":{"name":"Turkey", "geography_type":"country"}}
```

However, the following fails stating that the required property *name* is missing.

```
{"geography_group":[{"geography":{"name":"Turkey", "geography_type":"country"}}]}
```

If I remove `"required": ["name"]` it works, but I don't want to remove this.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few misconceptions here, but you broadly have the right idea.

I'm not sure what you believe the `oneOf` is doing here. In this case, it simply isn't required, and you can put `properties` and `additionalProperties` straight in the root schema.

In terms of your problem, while you've defined `geography` as a property at the root level, you haven't done so for an item object in the `geography_group` value array.

You want to change your `geograph_group` definition to the following...

```
"geography_group": {
      "type": "array",
      "description": "A grouping of discrete geographies that are not necessarily in a common hierarchy.",
      "items": {
        "properties": {
          "geograph": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/geography"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

As an aside, in draft-04 of JSON Schema, any keywords alongside `$ref` are ignored.

The key you use in the `definitions` object has no bearing on the validation of your data.

Comment: Thanks!  Works perfectly now!